# Is there a HOWTO to FCGI for deploying Satchmo?

Tags: python, django, deployment, fastcgi, satchmo

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/ details some setup for FCGI, but while it has material for the Apache config file, it omits the FCGI.

How can I create a site.fcgi file for a daemonized fastcgi process that is running on the same server bound to 127.0.0.1, and listening on port 1234?

--EDIT--

I have the following in my httpd.conf:

```
FastCGIExternalServer /home/jonathan/store/deploy/store.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:1234

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName steampunk.stornge.com
    DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/store/
    Alias /media /home/jonathan/store/media
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /store.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

In /home/jonathan/store/deploy/store.fcgi I have:

```
import os
import sys

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from site import addsitedir

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../")))

from django.conf import settings
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "store.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="true")
```

And I also have, running,

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

When I pull up http://[hostname], I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at [hostname] Port 80
```

http://[hostname]/media pulls up a populated index.

What could be improved, or might be causing trouble, in this use of FCGI? store.cgi was based on a couple of .fcgi files lying around which I used after not finding model FCGI files for Satchmo in the Django or FCGI docs. I don't trust it that far; I just haven't Googled something better.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeeded at deploying it with another option, FCGI:

In sites-enabled:

```
FastCGIExternalServer /home/jonathan/testfcgi/testfcgi.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:3033

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName testfcgi.jonathanscorner.com
    DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/testfcgi
    Alias /media /home/testfcgi/media
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /testfcgi.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]

    <Directory /home/jonathan/testfcgi/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is combined with a command line invocation of fcgi.